# Beginner in Java, Eclipse: How call method? (simple)

Tags: java, eclipse, function, method-call

I am beginner (newbie) in Java. I have downloaded the Eclipse environment to be able to code and run Java programs. Now my problem is simple: I am trying to run the code below, specifically I want to compute the so called *edit distance* between two words. I do not know how insert an input to this code (very simple right!). Take e.g. `w1=labd`, `w2=blad` and `w1len=4`, `w2len=4`. How do I insert this as an argument to my function?

**CODE**

```
int partDist(String w1, String w2, int w1len, int w2len) {
    if (w1len == 0)
      return w2len;
    if (w2len == 0)
      return w1len;
    int res = partDist(w1, w2, w1len - 1, w2len - 1) + 
    (w1.charAt(w1len - 1) == w2.charAt(w2len - 1) ? 0 : 1);
    int addLetter = partDist(w1, w2, w1len - 1, w2len) + 1;
    if (addLetter < res)
      res = addLetter;
    int deleteLetter = partDist(w1, w2, w1len, w2len - 1) + 1;
    if (deleteLetter < res)
      res = deleteLetter;
    return res;
  }
```

Should I add some command at the end of the code and run it? What would that be for this particular case?

Comment: Do you have a `main` method? Did you research "Hello, world!" in java?

Comment: Your application needs an entry point. In java, this is the `main` method. That needs to be part of your class.

Comment: Hi again, I am sorry but the title was obviously wrong. I am trying to call my function, that's all. No errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your function 'partDist' inside a class along with a main function and call it from main function like this :

```
    class YourMainClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
       System.out.println(partDist("labd", "blad", 4, 4)); // inorder to print the result to console
    }
    int partDist(String w1, String w2, int w1len, int w2len) {
    if (w1len == 0)
      return w2len;
    if (w2len == 0)
      return w1len;
    int res = partDist(w1, w2, w1len - 1, w2len - 1) + 
    (w1.charAt(w1len - 1) == w2.charAt(w2len - 1) ? 0 : 1);
    int addLetter = partDist(w1, w2, w1len - 1, w2len) + 1;
    if (addLetter < res)
      res = addLetter;
    int deleteLetter = partDist(w1, w2, w1len, w2len - 1) + 1;
    if (deleteLetter < res)
      res = deleteLetter;
    return res;
  }
  }
```

Comment: This will not compile since no arguments are provided for the call of `partDist`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out ! #Fixed

Comment: That didn't fix anything. I edited your post.